# How to render Image buffer from mongodb into handlebars

Tags: mongodb, express, multer

I am making ecommerce project , I am storing image buffer in mongo DB but the problem is I am not able to render it.

my code of controller code where I am trying to get data from db and transferring it to handlebars

```
const {CreateProduct}=require('../database/model')
exports.renderHomePage=async(req,res)=>{
    const data = await CreateProduct.find({});
    const imageBuffer = data[0].images
    console.log(" image ",imageBuffer)
    // res.send({images:imageBuffer})
    res.render('landing-page',{
        isCustomer:true,
        productData:data
});
```

}
}

The code is console logging image buffer and I am getting image buffer but res.send showing different JSON

here is my handlebar code

```
<div id="products-menu">
    {{#each productData}}
            <div id="product" class="single-product-class">
            <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{this.images}}" class="image-class" alt="product-image"></img>
            <div id="brands-name" class="brand-class">{{this.brand}}</div>
            <div id="product-name" class="product-name-class">{{this.name}}</div>
            <div class="price-div">
            <div class="rupee-sign-class">₹</div>
            <div id="price" class="price-class">{{this.price}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Mongo Db document screenshot

[image]

Comment: According to your screenshot, your handlebar code should use `{{this.images.$binary.base64}}`, not `{{this.images}}`.

Comment: nothing happening

Comment: need help !!!!!